# How can I add only the section in the headline of the default beamer template?

Tags: beamer

How can I show only the section name in the headline of the default beamer template (suppressing the subsection of all sections)?

I'm using the following beamer configurations.

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. If I take the information from your question and build such a MWE myself, I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlKsE.png Although I used a `\subsection` command in the MWE, I can only see the section titles in the headline, which seems to be the output you wanted. Please clarify.

Comment: MWE: `\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
contents
\end{frame}

\section{second section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
contents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: Adding `subsection=false` as an optional argument to the `miniframes` theme, does indeed and as expected, remove the subsections from the headline.